# Viewing SharePoint Tasks in Microsoft To Do

Tags: task-list, mytask

I have several SharePoint task lists synced to my Outlook but none of them display in my To-Do app.  My outlook tasks that aren't synced from sharepoint are displaying in To-Do, its just the SharePoint tasks that I am having trouble with.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Tasks do not sync to To-Do, so what you're seeing is by design.

Here is the list of [integrations](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/integrations-240c1078-2d74-4a7a-ae00-edae01b9b148?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

Comment: Even if the SharePoint tasks are synced to Outlook there is no way to take them from Outlook over to To-Do? I realize there isn't a direct integration but it seems like there has to be some sort of workaround once you get the tasks in Outlook...or I would hope at least!

Comment: They're not "in" Outlook, they're in SharePoint.

Comment: gotcha.  Okay, thank you!